Are any home lead testing kits effective for general use (not just paint)?
There are many people on TikTok and other social media loudly declaring “there’s lead in product X, it’s unsafe!” using lead testing kits they purchased online. Common subjects of these tests include children’s toys, and drinkware such as Stanley cups
and old McDonalds glasses. These kits may involve applying some reagent to the product’s surface, then applying a test strip and seeing if it changes color.
I’ve heard that many of these are misleading, because most home lead test kits are designed exclusively for testing paint. They're said to rely on assumptions about what other chemicals will be present in paint, and can have extremely high false positive rates when applied to other consumer goods. My understanding was that the only way to effectively test for the presence of lead is with more sophisticated laboratory equipment.
However, I’ve recently seen people promoting newer at-home lead tests that aren’t meant exclusively for paint. They appear to be based on this paper published in Nature Chemistry (which is way over my head, even the abstract), using some formulation that reacts with lead to produce something that fluoresces under ultraviolet light. The product Lumetallix appears to have been developed by some of the authors of that paper, and the product Fluoro-Spec appears to also be building on it. If true, that seems like an exciting development, but I'm not sure how to evaluate the credibility of their claims.
Are these, or any, at home lead testing kits effective for testing a broad range of consumer goods, such as children’s toys and drinkware, or are they snake oil?

Concerning lead paint, There are many different home test kits available on the market. But only US EPA approved test kits will give you a reliable result. Visit the US EPA’s Lead Test Kits website for a list of approved home test kits.

To test lead in drinking water, one may use at-home testing, but for an an accurate measure, a list of certified laboratories is provided by EPA. For other tests (i.e. not paint nor water), I believe that the kits are totally ineffective (I can't imagine a non destructive chemical process for products testing).

@Graffito hmm. It’s possible that this isn’t entirely non-destructive: some of the instructions on the lumetallix website mention that it works better if you rough up the surface a bit, such as by using sandpaper. It might have some reaction that does permanently effect the subject?

At the moment, this question is asking for shopping suggestions. It isn't clear what the claim is: That home lead testing kits are inaccurate on non-paint items? [No claim cited] That Lumetallix is accurate? [no claim cited] That Fluoro-spec is accurate? [No claim cited] Let's focus it onto one claim, and avoid asking for product suggestions.

Sorry,  my bad .

@Jeremy Lumetallix uses a combination of chemical reaction and photoluminescence, as exposed by the co-founders of the company in this article.

Are these products snake oil? Not necessarily: They do detect lead (some of the time), so in that sense they're not really lying. However, just because a product isn't snake oil doesn't mean it's it's reliable enough to be worth using. I'll note that detecting lead paint is much easier than detecting lead in a consumer good, since lead paint more homogoneous and has more lead.
Quoting Scitus, a manufacturer of lead test swabs:

Please note that when testing non-housepaint items, false negatives may occur for various reasons and factors it is not appropriate to use Scitus or another brand of swabs on consumer goods. (Check out our SCITUS GLOW TEST) Dangerous levels for children and adults may be found on objects whose surfaces either hide the lead from the swabs or have levels of lead that are low enough that it is not readily detectable by the test but, if handled by a person, will put off an amount of lead which if consumed would be harmful.

It is likely this warning was added in response to campaigning by Tamara Rubin.
To provide a scenario for the above issue: It's somewhat common (especially historically) to consumer goods using lead, then paint them using lead-free paint.  This is often a way to add a bit more weight to toys (e.g., for toy soldiers or chess pieces).  Since the surface of such a product has no lead, a lead test may generate a false negative.  Even ignoring Scitus's explanation of the issue, I'll note that such coatings degrade over time.
The above explanation takes it for granted that the lead test swabs are accurate: Plenty of brands are inaccurate.  Some tests don't warn customers to include a pretreatment step (needed to detect lead particulate).

Thanks for the good warnings about the caveats of such testing. Although my understanding was, even for detecting lead that is on the surface, of with appropriate pre-treatment, none of the older products on the market are suitable in any case, because they're not formulated to distinguish lead effectively from several other innocent materials that may be found in them. Tamara Rubin seems to be optimistically curious about Lumetallix tests, so maybe they are genuinely better than priors.
